# How to convert C++ 11 loop in to traditional loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having this error in my program error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':', I am using Visual c++ express 2010 and i think C++11 dosent support in VC 2010.

Can somone please modify this code and explain how to revert this for loop in traditional for loop ? ouFlexSignalInfo is a list data type from c++ stl

```
for(auto ouSignalInfo : ouFlexSignalInfo)   //C++11;
{
    SSignalInfo ouSignal;
    ouSignal.m_omEnggValue = ouSignalInfo.m_omEnggValue.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omRawValue = ouSignalInfo.m_omRawValue.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omSigName = ouSignalInfo.m_omSigName.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omUnit = ouSignalInfo.m_omUnit.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_msgName=ouFrame.m_strFrameName.c_str();
    SigInfoArray.Add(ouSignal);
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `ouFlexSignalInfo`?

Comment: Why don't you give it a shot? There are countless examples of iterating over containers in C++ on the web. What issue(s) are you having when you try to transform this yourself?

Comment: @Mat i tried but then i get error in this line ouSignalInfo.m_omEnggValue.c_str()

Comment: @user3656737: we can't help you understand your error and fix your code if you don't show it. Please [edit] your question with what you tried, and with the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use MS VC++ 2010 then the compiler supports a MS language extension for the range-based for loop. The code will look the following way

```
for each ( auto ouSignalInfo in ouFlexSignalInfo )
{
    SSignalInfo ouSignal;
    ouSignal.m_omEnggValue = ouSignalInfo.m_omEnggValue.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omRawValue = ouSignalInfo.m_omRawValue.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omSigName = ouSignalInfo.m_omSigName.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omUnit = ouSignalInfo.m_omUnit.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_msgName=ouFrame.m_strFrameName.c_str();
    SigInfoArray.Add(ouSignal);
}
```

Or it would be better to write

```
for each ( const auto &ouSignalInfo in ouFlexSignalInfo )
{
    SSignalInfo ouSignal;
    ouSignal.m_omEnggValue = ouSignalInfo.m_omEnggValue.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omRawValue = ouSignalInfo.m_omRawValue.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omSigName = ouSignalInfo.m_omSigName.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omUnit = ouSignalInfo.m_omUnit.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_msgName=ouFrame.m_strFrameName.c_str();
    SigInfoArray.Add(ouSignal);
}
```

As the type of ouFlexSignalInfo is unknown then you can use iterators. For example

```
#include <iterator>

for ( auto it = std::begin( ouFlexSignalInfo ); it != std::end( ouFlexSignalInfo ); ++it )
{
    SSignalInfo ouSignal;
    ouSignal.m_omEnggValue = it->m_omEnggValue.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omRawValue = it->m_omRawValue.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omSigName = it->m_omSigName.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_omUnit = it->m_omUnit.c_str();
    ouSignal.m_msgName = ouFrame.m_strFrameName.c_str();
    SigInfoArray.Add( ouSignal );
}
```

Comment: nice answer, but the last one is wrong. the std::end is called only once per range-based for loop

Answer (score 3):

it is roughly equivalent to:

```
auto iterBegin = std::begin(ouFlexSignalInfo);
auto iterEnd = std::end(ouFlexSignalInfo);

for(; iterBegin != iterEnd; ++iterBegin)
{
    auto ouSignalInfo = *iterBegin;
    //the rest of body
}
```

the `iterBegin` and `iterEnd` are iterators returned from the ouFlexSignalInfo members `begin` and `end`.

This kind of loop works for everything that has begin and end members

Comment: To be pedantic: Range based for loops for for some things without begin and end members too :)

Comment: @Massa I know, and `std::begin` and `std::end` work for something without begin and end members too :)

Comment: it works for all arrays as well, yes. I dont know if it works for anything else than standard containers, something with .begin and .end or arrays